# もし without ～たら or ～えば

Tags: grammar

Can anyone explain this use of もし? I thought it had to come before ～たら or ～えば.

> もしテレビで観たという方、ぜひぜひツイッターで教えてください。

Comment: I think that means "If that is the person you saw on television, please tell us on twitter!" I take もし to mean hypothetically. If you think about it, that's what it means as kind of an extra "if" in the たら and えば constructions

Comment: @virmaior, I think it means "People who saw it on TV, please tell us on twitter", for a couple of reasons. 1:方 is more likely to refer to the addressee than a 3rd person. 2:the missing なら/だったら/であれば, which would be missing in your interpretation, annoys me more than the superfluous もし in my interpretation.

Comment: @dainichi, I think you are right regarding the 方! Thanks for explaining. What do you think of "If you are a person who saw it on television, please tell us on twitter." (here I'm trying to deal with the という). I don't the もし winds up as superfluous with the translation I'm suggesting in this one the もし then pairs with という.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find this slightly non-standard, but fully understandable. I think it's a mix of the sentences

> テレビで観たという方、ぜひぜひ... People who saw it on TV, please...

and

> もしテレビで観たという方がいれば、ぜひぜひ... If anybody saw it on TV, please...

I don't think there's a hard rule that もし has to go with ～たら or ～えば, but it needs to precede some kind of condition. For example, もし～場合(は) and もし～とき(は) are also possible.